# React JS - Losing props on router change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a rail with a list of elements within - When I navigate to a different container and navigate back - props is lost almost? I get the following error.

Error:

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of null

    const actionLength = activeRail.props.children.length - 1;


    const later = () => {
----> callback.apply(context, callbackArgs)
      timeout = null
    }
```

I'm unsure what is causing this issue.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import key from 'keymaster';
import posed, { PoseGroup } from 'react-pose';

// import { fetchingPageData } from '../../actions';
import channelData from '../../data/channel-data';
import "./styles.scss";

// components
import MusicCard from '../../components/MusicCard/';
import Card from '../../components/JioCardAnimated/';
import TimeAndDate from '../../components/TimeAndDate';
import NotificationCentre from '../NotificationCentre';

// rails
import {accountsRail} from './rails/accounts';
import {searchRail} from './rails/search';
import {homeRail} from './rails/home';
import {onNowRail} from './rails/on-now';
import {moviesRail} from './rails/movies';
import {showsRail} from './rails/shows';
import {musicRail} from './rails/music';
import {appsRail} from './rails/apps';
import {gamesRail} from './rails/games';
import {myFilesRail} from './rails/my-files';
import {settingsRail} from './rails/settings';


function throttle(callback, wait, context = this) {
  let timeout = null
  let callbackArgs = null

  const later = () => {
    callback.apply(context, callbackArgs)
    timeout = null
  }

  return function() {
    if (!timeout) {
      callbackArgs = arguments
      timeout = setTimeout(later, wait)
    }
  }
}

const colors = [
  '#1030a4'
];

const Item = posed.div({
  initialPose: 'closed',
  hidden: {
    height: "155px",
    opacity: 0,
    delay: 0
  },
  closed: {
    height: "155px",
    opacity: 1,
    delay: 0
  },
  open: {
    height: "650px",
    opacity: 0.6
  }
});

const Rail = posed.div({
  open: {
    opacity: 1,
    staggerChildren: 50
  },
  closed: {
    opacity: 0,
    delay: 50
  }
});

const Buddy = posed.div({
  STATIC: {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 15,
    background: ({color}) => `${color}`,
    scale:1,
    opacity:1,
    transition: {
      type: 'spring',
    }
  },

  DOWN: {
    x: 0,
    y: 10,
    width: 15,
    background: ({color}) => `${color}`,
    scale: 0.9,
    opacity: 1,
    transition: {
      type: 'spring'
    }
  },

  UP: {
    x: 0,
    y: -10,
    width:20,
    background: ({color}) => `${color}`,
    scale:0.9,
    opacity:1,
    transition: {
      type: 'spring'
    },
  },

  EXPANDED: {
    x: -155,
    y: 0,
    width: 15,
    background: ({color}) => `${color}`,
    scale: 0.3,
    opacity: 0,
    transition: {
      type: 'spring',
      decay: 5,
      x: { duration: 100 }
    }
  },

  scrolled: {
    y: ({ target }) => target,
    transition: { type: 'spring' }
  },
});

const cardSizes = {
  small: 212 + 30,
  large: 568 + 30,
  music: 303 + 30
};


class MainMenu extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.className = this.keyScope = 'main-menu';
    this.rails=[];

    //Base Rails
    this.baseRails = [
      accountsRail,
      searchRail,
      homeRail,
      onNowRail,
      moviesRail,
      showsRail,
      musicRail,
      appsRail,
      gamesRail,
      myFilesRail,
      settingsRail,
    ];

    this.state = {
      active: false,
      indexX: 1,
      indexY: 1, // 0,
      menuItems: channelData,
      isExpanded: false,
      expanding: false,
      expandDelay: 800,
      buddy: 'STATIC',
      rails: [...this.baseRails],
      transform: cardSizes.small,
      notifications:[],
      pageActive: false,
      shouldAnimate: true,
    };

    this.expandTimeout = undefined;
    this.UIElements = [];
    this.notificationTimeout = undefined;
    this.longpress = 1300;
    this.delay = undefined;
  }

  UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
    // this.getItems();
    // this.setUIElements();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if(this.expandTimeout !== undefined) {
      clearTimeout(this.expandTimeout);
    }

    this.expandTimeout = setTimeout(()=> {
      this.onExpand(true);
    }, this.state.expandDelay*3);

    key('up', this.keyScope, this.onMoveVertical.bind(this, 'UP'));
    key('right', this.keyScope, this.onMoveHorizontal.bind(this, 'RIGHT'));
    key('down', this.keyScope, this.onMoveVertical.bind(this, 'DOWN'));
    key('left', this.keyScope, this.onMoveHorizontal.bind(this, 'LEFT'));
    key('enter', this.keyScope, this.onEnter.bind(this));
    key('m', this.keyScope, this.onToggleMenu.bind(this));
    key('c', this.keyScope, this.triggerNotification.bind(this));
    key.setScope(this.keyScope);
  }

  UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
      const index = this.state.rails[this.state.indexY].children.length + 3;
      this.setIndex(index, true);
  }

  setIndex(indexX, home) {
    const offset = 585;
    const transform = home
      ? ((((indexX - 2) * cardSizes.large) + cardSizes.small + cardSizes.music) - offset )
      : ((((indexX - 1) * cardSizes.large) + cardSizes.small) - offset )

    this.setState({
      indexX,
      transform,
    });
  }

  triggerNotification() {
    if(this.state.notifications.length > 0) {
      // We already have a notification, we don't need another.
      return;
    }

    const notifications = [
      {
        id:'incoming-call',
        icon: '',
        avatar: '/images/contacts/contact-prof.png',
        primary:'Incoming call',
        secondary: 'Aanya Singh',
        action: 'Press OK to answer',
        active: true
      }
    ];
    this.setState({
      notifications: notifications
    }, () => {

      this.notificationTimeout = setTimeout(()=> {

        this.notificationTimeout = undefined;
        this.setState({
          notifications:[]
        });
      }, 10 * 1000);

    })
  }

  onEnter() {
    const { history } = this.props;
    const { active } = this.state;
    const activeComponent = this[`rails-${this.className}-${this.state.indexY}`].props.children[this.state.indexX];

    if(this.state.notifications.length > 0) {
      history.push( {pathname: 'calling'} );
    }

    if (active && activeComponent.props.cardType === 'guide') {
      history.push( {pathname: 'guide'} );
    }

    if(active && activeComponent.props.cardType === 'music') {
      history.push( { pathname: "music-splash" });
    }
  }

  onExpand(force) {
    this.setState({
      isExpanded: (force) ? force : !this.state.isExpanded,
      expanding: true,
      buddy:'EXPANDED'
    }, (force)=> {
      setTimeout(()=> {
        this.setState({
          expanding: false,
          buddy:'FOCUS'
        });
      }, 250);
    });
  }

  handleKeyUp = (direction) => {
    key(direction.toLowerCase(), this.keyScope, this.onMoveHorizontal.bind(this, direction));
    document.removeEventListener('keyup', this.handleKeyUp.bind(this, direction));
    this.delay = undefined;
  }

  onMoveHorizontal = throttle((direction) => {
    const targetX = this.state.indexX + ((direction === 'RIGHT') ? 1 : -1);
    const activeRail = this[`rails-${this.className}-${this.state.indexY}`];
    const actionLength = activeRail.props.children.length - 1;
    let transform;
    const cardTarget = direction === 'LEFT' ? targetX : targetX - 1;
    const activeCard = activeRail.props.children[cardTarget];
    const { cardType } = activeCard.props;
    const baseLength = (actionLength + 1) / 3;

    const exit = () => {
      const { indexX } = this.state;

      if ((direction === 'RIGHT' && indexX === (baseLength * 2)) || (direction === 'LEFT' && indexX === baseLength)) {
        key.unbind(direction.toLowerCase(), this.keyScope, this.onMoveHorizontal.bind(this, direction));

        setTimeout(() => {
          this.handleKeyUp(direction);
        }, 1500);

        return false;
      }
    };

    this.delay = setTimeout(exit, this.longpress);

    if (direction === 'RIGHT' && targetX > (baseLength * 2)) {

      if (this.state.indexY === 1) {
        transform = this.state.transform - (((baseLength - 2) * cardSizes.large) + cardSizes.small + cardSizes.music);
      } else {
        transform = this.state.transform - ((baseLength * cardSizes.large) - (cardSizes.large - cardSizes.small));
      }

      this.setState({
        indexX: baseLength + 1,
        shouldAnimate: false,
        transform: transform,
      }, () => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.setState({
            shouldAnimate: true,
            transform: this.state.transform + cardSizes.small,
          });
        }, 0)
      });

      return;
    } else if (direction === 'LEFT' && targetX < 2) {
      const index = baseLength + 1;

      if (this.state.indexY === 1) {
        transform = ((index - 2) * (cardSizes.large) + cardSizes.small + cardSizes.music) - cardSizes.small - 90;
      } else {
        transform = ((index - 1) * (cardSizes.large) + cardSizes.small) - cardSizes.small - 90;
      }

      this.setState({
        indexX: index,
        shouldAnimate: false,
        transform: transform,
      }, () => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.setState({
            shouldAnimate: true,
            transform: this.state.transform - cardSizes.small,
          });
        }, 0)
      });

      return;
    }

    if (direction === 'RIGHT') {
      if (cardType === 'guide') {
        transform = this.state.transform + cardSizes.small;
      } else if(cardType === 'music') {
        transform = this.state.transform + cardSizes.music;
      } else {
        transform = this.state.transform + cardSizes.large;
      }
    } else {
      if (cardType === 'guide') {
        transform = this.state.transform - cardSizes.small;
      } else if(cardType === 'music') {
        transform = this.state.transform - cardSizes.music;
      } else {
        transform = this.state.transform - cardSizes.large;
      }
    }

    if(this.state.indexY === 0 || this.state.indexY === 10 || this.state.indexY === 7 || targetX < 0 || targetX > actionLength) {
      return;
    } else {
      this.setState({
        indexX: targetX,
        transform,
      });
    }

  }, 100)


  onMoveVertical(direction) {
    const offset = (direction === 'DOWN') ? 1 : -1;
    const targetY = this.state.indexY + offset;

    if(targetY > this.state.rails.length-1 || targetY < 0) {
      return;
    }

    else {
      const isHome = targetY === 1;
      const index = this.state.rails[targetY].children.length + (isHome ? 3 : 2);
      this.setIndex(index, isHome);

      this.setState({
        indexY: targetY,
        isExpanded: false,
        buddy: direction,
      }, ()=>{

        if(this.expandTimeout !== undefined) {
          clearTimeout(this.expandTimeout);
        }

        setTimeout(()=> {
          this.setState({
            buddy:'STATIC'
          });
        }, this.state.expandDelay / 2 );

        this.expandTimeout = setTimeout(()=> {
          this.onExpand(true);
        }, this.state.expandDelay);
      });
    }
  }

  onToggleMenu() {
    if(this.notificationTimeout !== undefined) {
      clearTimeout(this.notificationTimeout);
      this.notificationTimeout = undefined
    }

    this.setState({
      active: !this.state.active,
      pageActive: !this.state.pageActive,
      notifications: []
    }, () => {
      if(!this.state.active) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          // LVNOTE: Loop and reset all
          for (const name in this.refs) {
            const component = this.refs[name];

            if(component.onResetIndex) {
              component.onResetIndex();
            }
          }
        }, 250);
      }
    });
  }

  renderRails() {
    const styleX = {
      transform: `translate(-${this.state.transform}px, 0px)`,
      transition: this.state.shouldAnimate ? 'transform 200ms' : '0ms',
    };

    const rails = this.state.rails.map((d,i) => {
      let railTitle = d.title;
      let railTheme = d.theme;
      let railBecause = d.because;
      let railIcon = d.icon;
      const active = this.state.indexY === i;

      const cards = d.children.map((item, j) => {
        const sup = (j === 0)
          ? `${railBecause}`
          : j === 2
            ? 'New shows added'
            : '';

        return (
          <Card
            id={`Square-${i}-${j}`}
            title={item.title}
            metadata={item.metadata}
            image={`/images/artwork/${item.image}`}
            key={`Square-${i}-${j}`}
            type={'SquareCard'}
            sup={sup}
            pose={(active && this.state.indexX === (j + (i === 1 ? 2 : 1))) ? 'IF' : 'OOF'}
          />
        );
      });

      //Push music card to first rail
      //*** PLEASE NOTE - Issue with this card not becoming selected on home rail
      if(i === 1) {
        cards.unshift(
          <MusicCard
            railType="Home"
            cardType="music"
            id={i}
            image='/images/music/Manto_SnehaKhanwalkar_1x1_01.png'
            metadata="Playlist"
            title="Manto"
            type={'MusicCard'}
          />
        );
      }

      cards.unshift(
        <Card
          cardType="guide"
          icon={railIcon}
          id={`Guide-1`}
          theme={railTheme}
          title={railTitle}
          type={'SquareCard'}
        />
      );

      const children = [...cards, ...cards, ...cards];
      const slides = [];

      React.Children.forEach(children, (child, index) => {
        const { cardType } = child.props;
        const initialPose = cardType === 'music' ? 'OOF' : 'OOF';

        slides.push(React.cloneElement(child, {
          key: `card-${index}`,
          pose: (active && this.state.indexX === index) ? 'IF' : 'OOF',
          initialPose,
          className: (active && this.state.indexX === index) ? 'active' : '',
        }));
      });

      return (
        <Item
          pose={(active && this.state.isExpanded) ? 'open' : (this.state.isExpanded) ? 'hidden' : 'closed'}
          active={active}
          isExpanded={this.state.isExpanded}
          currentIndex={this.state.indexY}
          className={classNames('menuItem', { active })}
          key={`pose-${i}`}
        >
          <div className="item-heading">
            <p>{railTitle}</p>
          </div>

          {active &&
            <Rail
              className='rail'
              pose={(active && this.state.isExpanded) ? 'open' : 'closed'}
              ref={c => this[`rails-${this.className}-${i}`] = c}
              style={styleX}
            >
              {slides}
            </Rail>
          }
        </Item>
      );
    });


    return rails;
  }

  render() {
    const { menuItems } = this.state;
    const yPos = 155 - (155 * this.state.indexY);
    const styleY = { transform: `translate(0px, ${yPos}px)` };
    const target = (this.state.isExpanded && this.state.expanding) ? 155 : 0;

    return (
      <div>
        <div className={classNames(this.className, { active: true, 'page-active': this.state.pageActive, })}>
          <TimeAndDate />
          <div className='marker'></div>

          <div className='buddy-holder'>
            <Buddy
              className='Buddy'
              pose={this.state.buddy}
              poseKey={target}
              color={colors[0]}
              target={target}
            />
          </div>

          <div className='menu' style={styleY}>

            <PoseGroup selectedItemId={this.state.indexY} lastIndex={menuItems.length}>
              {this.renderRails()}
            </PoseGroup>
          </div>
        </div>

        <NotificationCentre notifications={this.state.notifications} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(MainMenu);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the actionRail based on state

```
const activeRail = this[`rails-${this.className}-${this.state.indexY}`];
```

On router change, the component will lose its state and wont be able to find the component you are aiming to get. You might want to move away from using state inside a component at all.

Comment: That's going to be quite the rework - is there any other way to get around this given it's a prototype?

Comment: What you could do is save the indexY value into localStorage on ComponentWillUnmount and on returning, retrieve the value from localStorage on ComponentDidMount. Its a hacky solution but would work for a prototype.